# how to sharing a karaf feature without a maven repository?

Tags: maven, karaf

I need to share a feature with someone with whom I don't share a repository. Is it a good idea to just zip the maven artifact directory directory from my local maven repository and send it over ? 
the directory has feature xml pom and jars. Is there a better way of doing this short of sharing a common central repository ?

Answer (score 1):

For that i would use a KAR File, it's one of the recommended ways to provision karaf features, it will package your bundle, the feature and all dependencies in one archive there are two ways to generate kar files:

First one, you can generate using karaf itself:

```
karaf@root()> kar:create your-feature
```

The seconde one, you can generate the kar file using the following maven plugin with your project as a kar packaging.

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you can just drop the kar archive at the deploy folder, or install it using the kar:install command.

For more informations check https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/kar

Comment: With this method, I have found that some m2 stored dependencies are missing which causes the install using the KAR archive to fail. Do you know of a way to solve this issue?